# Hopping integral for Hydrogen chain

Tags: solid-state-physics, metals, tight-binding

When calculating a hydrogen chain in the tight binding approx., one comes across the hopping integral:

$<m+1|V_{m+1}|m>$

Where $|m>$ is the 1s-Wavefunction at position m and $V_m$ is the coulmb potential of the proton at position m. Here i sketched the situation:
[image]
Setting m = 0, using the atom distance R this integral is:

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|r|}e^{-|r-R|}\frac{1}{|r-R|} dr$

If I only evaluate the space between the atoms I get:

$\int_0^R e^{-r}e^{r-R}\frac{1}{R-r} = e^{-R}\int_0^R \frac{1}{R-r}$

Which basically comes down to evaluating $ln(0)$, which is infinite.

However,  if I do this numerically I get a usefull plot:
[image]

Which looks pretty similar to the plot my book. Is my calculation correct or my program?

How do I calculate this with pen & paper? Do I have to do it in 3D?